# What's the difference between String and string in Dart?

Tags: dart

I can't understand why in some docs the String method is capitalized, but in some docs the same method is not. `string` vs `String`.

What is difference?

Comment: Where is it not capitalized?

Comment: What do you mean by String _method_ ?

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that `String` is a type and `string` is not.

For more details it depends on the context.

Comment: Can I write `string name = 'foo'`  ?

Comment: No. Here `string` is used as type and needs to be uppercase.

Comment: When it can be lowercase?

Comment: `int string = 15;` ;-). In lowercase it's just an identifier. Where did you see it bring used lowercase?